# name 'Sequential' is not defined Python3 Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

```
import numpy
import keras.models
import tensorflow
seed = 7

numpy.random.seed(seed)
dataset = numpy.genfromtxt("student-por.csv",delimiter=";")
X = dataset[:,0:33]
Y = dataset[:,8]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) # Fit the model

scores = model.evaluate(X,Y)
print("%s: %s" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Error :

> #Exception 错误:
>       #Using TensorFlow backend.
>       #Traceback (most recent call last):
>       #  File "test.py", line 11, in 
>       #    model = Sequential()
>       #NameError: name 'Sequential' is not defined
>       #很奇怪 他居然显示Sequential()有问题 我确认好多次我没打错了 引用库也不知道有什么问题

It is strange that he actually showed that there is a problem with Sequential (). I confirmed many times that I did not type the reference library incorrectly and did not know what was wrong.

Comment: You haven't imported `Sequential`.  Use `model = keras.models.Sequential()`.

Answer (score 25):

You should import it.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: for anyone using Keras from Tensorflow

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using some packages or libraries in the code, you need to import it. Import the model libraries for concern model.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
```